# Using Progressive Web Apps on EOS7?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm trying to use progress web apps on EOS7 but have been unsuccessful. I'm using the flatpak version of chrome and when i select the install as web app option, i receive a message saying that the browser doesn't have permission to access the application folder...I tried to grant permission but ended up deleting the keyring. How can i successfully install PWAs on EOS7 using chrome?

Comment: From https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.google.Chrome" "NOTE: This wrapper is not verified by, affiliated with, or supported by Google."

Comment: Google Chrome does not have an officially supported flatpak release. The way to go in this case is to download the .deb from their site and install it using dpkg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vlad mentioned in his comment, Google does not offer an officially supported Flatpak of Chrome. You can install it as a `.deb` file, though:

1. Using a browser or terminal, download the `.deb` from here:

   ```
   https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
   ```
2. Install it by double-clicking the file in the UI or, if you prefer to use the terminal, with `apt`:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
   ```

When installing Chrome, the source for the package will be added to your `apt` sources list. You can confirm it exists by checking the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory for a file named `google-chrome.list`. This will ensure that Chrome receives updates as they become available.

Comment: Thank you. The deb version works